# How to compile pgfmanual

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation

I'am trying to compile pgfmanual with texlive 2020. Codes are cloned from [pgf-tikz/pgf](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf).

I simply run `make` under path `pgf/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-pgftex/en`, but got an error `pgfmanual-en-macros.tex not found`. I download the file from [CTAN](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfmarginpar/doc/pgfmanual-en-macros.tex), and put it in `pgf/doc/generic/pgf/text-en`.

Then rerun `make`, and got the error

```
I do not know the key `/codeexample/preamble` to which you passed `\usetikzlibrary {intersections}`
```

What is the correct way to compile pgfmanual?

Comment: It's literally in the README of the repo you cloned: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/README.md#development

Comment: Thanks! I do not realize that the last command is to build the manual.

Comment: There is an error, though.  You have to `cd pgf` before you can run `texlua`.  I'll update that.